# Running Ubuntu from USB SSD across multiple systems

Tags: 16.04, usb, ssd

Is it possible to run Ubuntu from a USB SSD with persistance? I want it so I can just switch from one PC to another at will as I will be using this drive for programming and general tasks outside of my work laptop which I don't want to touch.
Will a standard install achieve this or do I need to use something like mkusb or some other tool?, in addition would I be able to update this system when a new update rolls out for example 17.04.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible to run Ubuntu from a USB SSD with persistance. Either *persistent live* by mkusb or *installed* (like installed into an internal drive). I use both methods. An installed system can be updated and upgraded completely (including kernels and drivers) and is rather portable between computers. A persistent live system is more portable, but kernels and drivers cannot be updated and upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

A USB 3.0 portable SSD is a little bit larger than a USB flash drive. They are available from different manufacturers in sizes up to 1TB. Ubuntu can be installed on a USB 3.0 portable SSD as a live USB with persistence in the usual way, for example with the built-in Startup Disk Utility application. In my experience a live Ubuntu USB cannot be successfully upgraded to a newer release. It's better to install the latest LTS release and stick with it.

Beyond that, I'm pessimistic about the idea of using a portable drive for programming. Programming often requires installing a lot of software, which seems to cause more problems than it's worth when running Ubuntu on live USB media, especially intermittent freezing due to the higher latency of the USB connection.